# node-webkit-agent wont connect to my application

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-webkit-agent

I've been trying to debug my node application as I keep getting 'stack size exceeded' errors. I've replaced global accidental vars with the prefix var for declaration but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I tried using node-inspector but apparently the profiling tab is not available anymore. I tried finding other methods of analyzing my garbage collection with heap analysis tools but they all seem to be paid services that I can't really afford just for a grad school project.

I tried using node-webkit-agent but I am not able to connect to the agent. After running my file, `node myFile.js` and entering `kill -USR2 (pid of myFile)`, whenever I restart my app again I get the following error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xvz4rnf69zc68d/Screenshot%202014-10-07%2018.17.42.png?dl=0[image]

I don't really know why this is happening... I'm running it on a free EC2 instance and have gotten node-inspector to work previously but as mentioned its not helping me to debug memory leaks. I think I may start setting up node-memwatch as I'm not really sure why this is so hard to get working and am not really very optimistic about using open source free tools with a GUI for memory usage for nodeJS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you already have something running on the port where you try to launch your app, netstat will tell you which process. kill the process then you can launch again

Comment: i changed it to run on 9998 to tests and it says `a proxy got connected waiting for commands` but i still have trouble accessing it in the browser. I'm trying to use the front-end, by running node-devtools-webkit-agent-frontend. When I run it with the default value of `9090/inspector.html?host=localhost:9998&page=0` I get the block that shows: `websocket_closed`. when i remove the page=0 i get a blank interface...

Comment: that's a different question altogether and not one we can solve using the info you provided.